# C++ private copy constructor issue

Tags: c++, syntax

I am building a small C++ app and I was looking to make a private copy constructor for my reference holder.

When I use my class in my main, everything works, but when I try to test it with Google Test, I get an error stating that my copy constructor is private

```
TEST (Library, constructorParams) {
    Library lib = Library("my Library");
    ASSERT_EQ("my Library", lib.getNom());
}
```

Library.h (there is no definition for the copy constructor and the assignation operator in my .cpp)

```
class Library {
public:
    ...
private:
    ...

    Library (const Library& obj);
    Library & operator=(const Library& obj);
};
```

Why am I getting an error for my private copy constructor (might it be a bad usage in my Tests?)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here

```
Library lib = Library("my Library");
```

you are semantically performing a copy construction from a temporary object constructed on the RHS. Even of the compiler might optimize copies out, the copy constructor needs to be publicly accessible.

Try this instead:

```
Library lib("my Library");
```

See more on [copy initialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm).

Answer (score 4):

```
Library lib = Library("my Library");
```

On this line you try to copy-construct an object of type `Library`, but this can't be done as its copy-constructor is private. You should instead do this:

```
Library lib("my Library");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the copy constructor from this line of code

```
Library lib = Library("my Library");
```

And you have defined it as a private method of that class.

That operation is not related to a call to the assignment operator (which you mention in the question), this is more clear if you consider its equivalent:

```
Library lib(Library("my Library"));  // Here the invocation of the copy 
                                     // constructor is more explicit
```

With the code in this format, it is also more clear that there's no need to first create the object in a temporary than call the copy constructor to create another instance of that object.

The correct way should be:

```
Library lib("my Library");
```